# How to pull the rt-source metric using google analytic API?

Tags: google-analytics, postman, google-analytics-api, metrics

I am new to using APIs in general as well as using Google Analytics API. I am trying to call the google analytics traffic results from a website using google analytics API. When using the rt-source metric I get a missing parameter error. When I try to add the bounce rate as a parameter I get an unknown metric error. Please can someone advise what I am doing wrong or if the problem is at the client's side. See image for example of code. [image: Traffic API code example]Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  In order to test your call i need to see the call you are making

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation for [realtime.get](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get)  You will find that at least one metric is required

[image]

So as the error message says you need to add a metric.  From what i can see you have only added a dimension

```
curl \
  'https://analytics.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=ga%3AUa-12445433&metrics=rt%3AactiveUsers' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

Consult the documentation for a full list of [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets)  that can be used with the realtime api.  You will find that bounce rate is not one of them.

[rt:source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/trafficsources#rt:source) is valid though. try rt%3source remember it needs to be html encoded.  Remember this is a dimension not a metric so must be sent in the dimension paramater

```
curl \
  'https://analytics.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=ga%XXXXXX&metrics=rt%3AactiveUsers&dimensions=rt%3Asource&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

The real time report for traffic source by default uses rt:activeUsers Just look at the report its telling you what the metric is

[image]

Comment: Thanks the documentation helped a lot. But it does not have the specific metrics related to rt: source under traffic. Where can I find those metrics?

Comment: The Realtime api is extremely limited in what dimensions and metrics are available/ supported.    If your not finding the one your looking its because its not supported.  You may want to switch to the reporting api.   But the data in that is not really time and can take a few days for processing to complete.

Comment: With regard to rt:source that is a dimension not a metric so it can only be used if you send it as a dimension.  You still need to send a valid metric of course.

Comment: Sorry, I am new so also a little bit lost. If I understand correctly my dimension is rt:source but I cannot use this by itself because I need to specify a parameter which is the metric. But google analytics does not have any metrics available for any of the traffic dimensions so there is no way of getting the traffic information using the google analytics api? Unless I use the reporting api which is not in real time so could take days?

Comment: Thats because as the decimation stats.  Metric is required. You need to send a metric.   check the [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets) page pick one that falls under the metric column.   This is how google analytics works you cant have metrics in the Realtime api if they haven't completed processing.   Which metric are you looking for exactly?

Comment: So I am trying to get the traffic source information displayed by google analytics for a particular website. But on the dimensions and metrics list that you sent under traffic it only displays all the traffic dimensions such as rt:source but with no related metrics. The metric column is empty under the traffic section

Comment: The default for that report is rt:activeUsers

Comment: Ok great, thank you so much that makes sense. I learned a lot and the documents you sent were also very useful.